# Яндекс карты. Добавить панель на карту

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите возможно ли такую панель добавить на карту?

https://yadi.sk/i/FSrYQfqb3X7Cex

Сейчас это сделано средствами css, соответственно при вкл "Полноэкранный режим" этой панели нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API позволяет добавлять на карту собственные элементы управления через [интерфейс `IControl`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IControl-docpage/?from=SO).

[Такой пример есть в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO)